Как настроить multicast (Juniper srx240)?
Был настроен выход в Интернет, но очень хотелось бы, чтобы работала IPTV приставка и гонять мультикаст. Не получается создать несколько VLAN для PP0 интерфейфейса.
Вот участок кода:
Настройка PP0:
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 ppp-options chap default-chap-secret "$9$************************"
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 ppp-options chap local-name LOGIN***
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 ppp-options chap passive
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 pppoe-options underlying-interface ge-0/0/0.0
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 pppoe-options idle-timeout 0
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 pppoe-options auto-reconnect 10000
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 pppoe-options client
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet negotiate-address

Порт 0 подтягиваем к PPPoE:
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 encapsulation ppp-over-ether


set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.75.1
set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 qualified-next-hop pp0.0 preference 5

set vlans inet vlan-id 3021
set vlans inet l3-interface vlan.3021

set security zones security-zone untrust interfaces pp0.0
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces vlan.3021


А какое отношение к вопросу имеет с++ ????

В других разделах не давал создавать тему.
